# How to restore desktop icons locations?

Tags: windows, desktop, icons

After updating video drivers and flipping screen resolution, locations of all my desktop icons are lost (again). However, I have a backup of the system disk. Is it possible to restore locations from there? What file holds that information?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried right clicking on the desktop and going to "sort by", there you have choices of Name, Size, Item type and Date modified. I usually use Item type. I always get the icon for Recycle Bin in the top left corner.

You click once it may go there, if it hasn't it will rearrange them again to get it there if it did not do it the first time. I am just using this as an example.

Comment: I need to restore original icon locations, not to sort them.

Comment: Then I will have to presume you are missing icons. There is only one that is on the desktop after the OS is installed, that is the recycle bin. Unless it is from the bundled crapware that is on many OEM computers, otherwise every icon after the OS is installed is added by the user or programs that are installed by the user. When you referred to locations, it sounded as though they were in the wrong place on the desktop, therefore sorting so it seemed, was what was needed.

Comment: Not missing. I need to restore their **original locations**

Comment: I am not understanding what you mean. I will take another shot at it. Are the icons, no longer "pointing" to the program they represent? As in you click on them an there is a prompt that say the file or program it refers to is missing or moved?

Comment: @Jack - It sounds like he is referring to the problem where you place desktop icons where you want them and after certain system operations you find the locations changed.  He wants to be able to restore the icon locations to the original layout.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend DesktopOK (http://www.softwareok.de/?Freeware/DesktopOK) it helps you to store the settings you have so if anything gets messed up you can go back to any previously saved settings - not sure if this helps for what you try to achieve